# ATMega328P - How to protect application flash memory from reading by ISP

Tags: bootloader, atmega328p

I created boot-loader code for reprogramming application section. I use Wiznet W5500 SPI to Ethernet chip, my goal is that only i can reprogram the device using LAN / WAN. The read write command is different from atmel's standard, so i assume that no one will know.

The problem is: How do i set the lock bits to prevent reading the application by ISP?

Comment: Security by obscurity is always a bad idea. There will always be someone to find out, if there is enough motivation. However, you might block the casual user.

Answer (score 2):

Every AVR microcontroller has Lock-bits to protect the memory. From the datasheet:
[image: Atmega328P lock bits]
And if you're using 'ProgIsp' programmer, simply click the button like the following image:
[image: ProgIsp]
Then, set two lock bits to 0 and press the write button:
[image: Fuse bits]
By doing this, you can not read the flash and EEPROM but you will be able to re-flash the chip. However, every time you re-flash the chip, lock bits will be set to 1 again and you need to lock it after flashing.

Comment: if i set the lock bits (LB1 & LB2 to zero), will i be able to rewrite the application section again in the future using my bootloader which i have stored in the chip?

Comment: Only with full chip erase. So not with bootloader.